# Domain object model: query by id vs object

Tags: java, object-oriented, unit-testing, domain-model, mocking

Let assume I have two simple model classes: `Product` and `Brand`

It is obvious I have a query method in `Product`  class like this

```
Product product = Product.findById(123);
```

What if, I want to query products by brand?

```
ArrayList<Product> products = Product.findByBrand(234);
// or
ArrayList<Product> products = Product.findByBrand(new Brand("ABC", 234));
```

Assume 234 is the brand ID in the database.

I assume the 2nd way of writing make the method more easy to test as I can mock the `Brand` class in my unit test, right?

Answer (score 5):

For unit-testing the `findByBrand` method, there is no real difference between passing in a `Brand` object or just an ID.

The difference is more relevant for the code calling `findByBrand`.
In the large majority of cases, that code should already be dealing with `Brand` objects, so passing that as an argument to `findByBrand` makes the most sense.

The only reason for `findByBrand` to accept a plain ID would be if (nearly) *all* current and expected callers are already naturally working with Brand-IDs without having corresponding `Brand` objects.

Comment: Notice that "... if (nearly) all callers are already naturally working with Brand-IDs ..." might occur inside the library code (i.e. other model classes), whereas application code might prefer to use `Brand` objects exclusively for safety and ease-of-you. In that case, it might make sense to use visibility.

Comment: @rwong: You are right. It it likely that application code will use/prefer `Brand` objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's more than just whether you can mock a `Brand` object or not.

First, I'll assume your `Product` is really a [Data Access Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object), and not a simple [Java Bean/DTO/POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object#Value_Objects_in_Java).

The *real* question to ask is, how long will this assertion hold?

> Assume 234 is the brand id of the brand in database.

Will simple `int` values become `long` in the future, necessitating all methods interacting with a 'brand ID' to be changed from accepting an `int` to `long`? Will it become an alphanumeric, which might be possible to remain as an `int` (plausibly - if we're talking hexadecimals smaller than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and there is now a conversion method/utility somewhere to turn `"AA"` into `170`) or will the whole type-changing parade enter the `String` phase?

The one slim benefit I can see for accepting an `int` is that you don't have to pay particular attention to a `null` input. Well, there's still the extremely odd chance of a `null` explicitly casted as an `Integer` and then getting auto-boxed, but you probably have other concerns then.